# Passing variable to another PHP page gives error

Tags: php

I am trying to run a php script from my controller with argument which I need in another page using below command,

```
$script = shell_exec("php test.php $var1"); // controller.php
```

```
global $argv;  //if I add this then error changes to null value error
$argument1 = $argv[1]; //this I am trying in another test.php page which is in different directory
```

Getting error undefined argv.

Comment: what is there in $argv? and where is it defined in your code?

Comment: What is the output when you `var_dump($argv);`?

Comment: "_Note: This variable is not available when register_argc_argv is disabled._" Make sure that `register_argc_argv` is set in your `php.ini`

Comment: I have not defined anywhere. I tried global $argv but that give null value error

Comment: @Hirumina: `$argv` is the list of arguments when you execute a php script via command line, and it's definfed by PHP

Comment: @camaulay on var_dump($argv) it say undefined variable: argv

Comment: @kerbh0lz its already enabled

Comment: `$argument1 = $argv[1];` -> is that all on test.php? do you access $argv inside a function or class?

Comment: @catcon as of now this is the only thing, neither in class or function, its in starting of page

Comment: "_which is in different directory_" Wouldn't you need the path to that "different directory" in your shell_exec call? How do you check for output of your shell_exec? Can you post the exact error message you get? What OS are you using? Which version of PHP?

Comment: i am changing directory before trigger shell_exec using chdir("...")

Answer (score 1):

> shell_exec()
> takes one parameter which is only used to hold command in your case you are holding command output and return variable all in one. you Must use
> exec()
> it takes three parameters command, output and return variable.

```
<?php
session_start(); // DO CALL ON TOP OF BOTH files
$command = "date"; //pass any valid command
$output;
exec($command, $output, $var1); // controller.php
$_SESSION['output'] = $output;
if($var1){
//if $var1 have true value it will redirect to next file with values
header('Location: test.php);
}
?>
```

in your test.php file use this

```
<?php
session_start(); // DO CALL ON TOP OF BOTH PAGES
$var1 = $_SESSION['output'];
$argument1 = $var1[1]; 
print_r($argument1);

?>
```

Through this method you will get your value from one file to another.

Comment: PHP Notice &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Undefined variable: argv&#039; 
Same error on test.php when using $argument1= $argv[1];

Comment: Just edited the solution kindly try this and let me know i ran the whole code by myself and its working i am able to get value on test.php with this method